# 10k views badge bugged?

Tags: support, badges

I didn't get badge for 10k views on

[What is the .632+ rule in bootstrapping?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/96739/what-is-the-632-rule-in-bootstrapping/96750#96750)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The "famous-question" badge is awarded to the asker after the question is viewed 10k times. In this case, you answered the question, which is why you did not get it.